# Avoid bind recursion for NumericProperty

Tags: python, kivy

I need change property in function which is called when property changed. This calls recursion. For example:

```
from kivy.app   import App;
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget;
from kivy.uix.button import Button;
from kivy._event        import EventDispatcher;

class test(Button, EventDispatcher):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__();

        self.bind(size = self.change_width);


    def change_width(self, instance, value):
        print('im changed');
        self.width-= 20;
        


t = test();
t.width = 120;

class testApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return t;

if __name__ == '__main__':
    testApp().run();
```

When anywhere size of the button changed, i need make this width smaller. Is there any way to avoid recursion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can avoid the recursion by turning off the binding when you change the `width`:

```
def change_width(self, instance, value):
    print('im changed');
    self.unbind(size=self.change_width);
    self.width -= 20;
    self.bind(size=self.change_width);
```